# Rewrite rules diretcory wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting

i'm trying to figure out why my rewrite rules doesn't work ,
i just want to rewrite some part of the url ,
like this one for example : 
/guiwordpress/**wp-content**/themes/storefront/  would be replace by 
/guiwordpress/**guit**/themes/storefront/

here is my htacces file :

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /guiwordpress/ 
#WriteCheckString:1517022973_21408
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_MOD_REWRITE:On]

RewriteRule ^guit/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-content/themes/storefront/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^guinc/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-includes/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^guicontent/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-content/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule> 


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /guiwordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /guiwordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The part who goes wrong is here :

```
RewriteRule ^guit/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-content/themes/storefront/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^guinc/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-includes/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^guicontent/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-content/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've messed with apache, but I believe you need your rules to match starting with a '/'. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/guit/(.+) /guiwordpress/wp-content/themes/storefront/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Assuming that the url is something like https://example.com/guit/*

Comment: Doh, missed the RewriteBase